How to use Plancherel's formula in analytic number theory?
I have read the report paper icm2018 by Matomaki and Radziwill, specifically page 342 where they provide a sketch of the proof of Theorem 4. On that page, they state:
"By an application of Plancherel, $$\tag5\int_{X}^{2 X}\left|\sum_{x<n \leq x+H} \mu(n)\right|^{2} d x$$ is (essentially) equivalent to $$\int_{0}^{X / H}\left|\sum_{X<n \leq 2 X} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^{1+i t}}\right|^{2} d t=o(1) .\tag6$$"
However, I am unsure how to deduce (6) from (5) using Plancherel. Could you clarify the steps involved in this deduction?

It's just a heuristic. See their Annals paper for the rigorous details.

Thank you for your comment! I noticed that in their original Annals paper, they used Perron's formula to achieve the result, and I'm not sure if this is equivalent to "by Plancherel formula". Additionally, I'm still unclear on how to see the correctness of equation (6) from a heuristic perspective, especially in the context of applying the Plancherel formula(For instance, why the integral variable change from $X-2X$ to $0-X/H$, and why the inner sum also changed from short interval to long). If you have any further insights, I'd appreciate it if you could share them.

You can regard
$$
\sum_{X<n\le2X}{\mu(n)\over n^{1+it}}=\sum_{X<n\le2X}{\mu(n)\over n}\cdot e^{-it\log n}
$$
as an analog of Fourier transform, which explains why the authors relate (5) and (6) by Plancherel.
